# Can't load a background image

Tags: html, css

I watched a Youtube video that teaches how to create a site's landing page, so I'm trying to set a background using CSS and it just won't load.

```css
#showcase {
    background-image: url('..img/showcase.jpg');
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    height: 100vh;
}
```

The background remains blank.

Comment: Do you get not found error on `console`?

Comment: Usually a path issue.

Comment: do inspect element on the background and see if the URL resolves to a valid image

Comment: for a first glance remark, the path for the image may be incorrect. Do you have a 404 error on the console ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The file path that you're currently using is incorrect. Use the following:

```
../img/showcase.jpg
```

We added a simple `/` after `..`

We use `./` when the file to import is on the same folder as the file importing (os a subfolder). `../` is used when the file to import is one directory before the file importing, and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have "showcase.jpg" inside img folder at the root of your file?

If this seems confusing, move the showcase.jpg image in the same folder as you css file is and set the path in css as

```
background-image:url('showcase.jpg');
```

Answer (score 0):

File path `..img/showcase.jpg` depends from the position of the css file and the image file.

`..img/showcase.jpg` is wrong, maybe you need to use '../img/showcase.jpg' that means: the image is positioned respect the css in the img folder inside the parent folder of the css file.

If you have some difficult to find the correct relative path try to use ti tool online:
https://www.stevebreese.com/Relative-Path-Calculator